# Spring Security Configuration filter any requests except a specific endpoint?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have the following code

```
http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/users/login","/token/refresh").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterAfter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(),UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
```

And I thought it mean do not filter requests that match /users/login or /token/refresh, but filter any request that doesn't match that.
But it still filters on /users/login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I solved in an old project is requiring auth on every endpoint

```
http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterAfter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(),UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
```

and ignoring security on the desired endpoints

```
 public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users/login");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
.antMatchers("/users/login").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/token/refresh").permitAll()
```

Comment: This doesn't work, even if i do it only for one of the endpoints it still filters is.

Answer (score -1):

csrf is enabled by Spring Security automatically. Try disabling it.

http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/users/login","/token/refresh").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().addFilterAfter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(),UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)